# Is it possible to implement gradual movement of an object to given coordinates in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

here is the sample code that i have tried:

```py
x[0] = 10
y[0]=10
x[1] = 40
y[1]=40
width=10
height=10
pygame.draw.rect(win,(0,0,255),(x[1],y[1],width,height))
pygame.draw.rect(win,(0,0,255),(x[0],y[0],width,height))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to slight change the position in the application loop.

Define a start position (`start`), end position (`end`) and velocity (`speed`):

```py
start = 10, 10
end = 40, 40
speed = 1
```

Init the current position. Compute the vector form the current position to the end position (`dx`, `dy`) in the application loop and change the current position by the speed in the direction to the target:

```py
pos = start[:]
while run:
    # [...]

    dx = end[0] - pos[0]
    dy = end[1] - pos[1]
    dist = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
    if dist > speed:
        pos = pos[0] + dx*speed/dist, pos[1] + dy*speed/dist
```

Note, [`math.hypot`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=hypot#math.hypot) computes the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) and `(dx/dist, dy/dist)` is a [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) (a unit vector has length 1).

Draw the object at the current position (`pos`) in every frame:

```py
pygame.draw.rect(win,(0,0,255),(round(pos[0]), round(pos[1]), width, height))
```

If you have a list of positions:

```py
x = [60, 140, 140, 60]
y = [60, 140, 60,  140]
```

Then `start` and `end` have to be set from the positions in the list. Use a list index `current_i` to track the current start position. Increment the index, if the object has reached the current target position (`end`).
See the example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = [60, 140, 140, 60]
y = [60, 140, 60,  140]

width, height = 10, 10
speed = 1
current_i = 0
pos = x[current_i], y[current_i]

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    start = x[current_i], y[current_i]
    end = x[current_i % len(x)], y[current_i % len(y)], 
    dx = end[0] - pos[0]
    dy = end[1] - pos[1]
    dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
    if dist > speed:
        pos = pos[0] + dx*speed/dist, pos[1] + dy*speed/dist
    else:
        pos = end[:]
        current_i = current_i + 1 if current_i < len(x)-1 else 0

    win.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(win,(0,0,255),(round(pos[0]), round(pos[1]), width, height))
    pygame.display.flip()
```